# Processing data from API for table rendering

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, ember.js

I receive from API something like that:

```
"stats": [
    {
        "label": 2016,
        "stats": {
            "return": 4,
            "stddev": 4,
            "sharpe": 4,
            "maxddown": 4
        }
    },
    {
        "label": 2015,
        "stats": {
            "return": 5,
            "stddev": 5,
            "sharpe": 5,
            "maxddown": 5
        }
    },
    {
        "label": 2014,
        "stats": {
            "return": 6,
            "stddev": 6,
            "sharpe": 6,
            "maxddown": 6
        }
    }
]
```

I should transform the data to array of objects which I shall be used to rendering a table in Ember app. I have no idea how... The final data for table should be looks like:

```
const tableData = [
    {
        name: 'return',
        2016: 4,
        2015: 5,
        2014: 6
    }, {
        name: 'stddev',
        2016: 4,
        2015: 5,
        2014: 6 
    }, {
        name: 'sharpe',
        2016: 4,
        2015: 5,
        2014: 6  
    }, {
        name: 'maxddown',
        2016: 4,
        2015: 5,
        2014: 6  
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Get the keys of the `stats` and iterate over it. In the iteration cycle you need to iterate over all `stats`, access the property of each `stats` with the selected `key` and create your object.

```js
const stats = [
    {
        "label": 2016,
        "stats": {
            "return": 4,
            "stddev": 4,
            "sharpe": 4,
            "maxddown": 4
        }
    },
    {
        "label": 2015,
        "stats": {
            "return": 5,
            "stddev": 5,
            "sharpe": 5,
            "maxddown": 5
        }
    },
    {
        "label": 2014,
        "stats": {
            "return": 6,
            "stddev": 6,
            "sharpe": 6,
            "maxddown": 6
        }
    }
];

const keys = Object.keys(stats[0].stats);

const mapped = keys.map(key => {

  const obj = { name: key };

  stats.forEach(item => {
     obj[item.label] = item.stats[key]; 
  });
  
  return obj;
});

console.log(mapped);
```